# how to hide items behind a panel in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

i used the following code for control display

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication29.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid >
        <Border Margin="100" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Canvas>
                <Label Content="This is test" FontSize="129" Width="400" Height="200"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

I want to display it as the 2nd one which is cut from below if its `size` is greater then the `parent control` or if `margin is negative`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use ClipToBounds property of Canvas to True

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication29.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid >
    <Border Margin="100" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
            <Label Content="This is test" FontSize="129" Width="400" Height="200"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image]

```
and you get the Result like this
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use `ClipToBounds="True"` properties for your border

```
 <Grid >
        <Border Margin="100" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Canvas  >
                <Label Content="This is test" FontSize="129" Width="400" Height="200"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```